# How can I deal with crash correctly while using firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, crashlytics

In my flutter project, I just using firebase like this:

```dart
//main.dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

It looks like firebase can only catch crashes when using like

```dart
 final result = await someThrowErrorFunctions;
```

But if I deal with any functions like:

```dart
try {
  final result = await someThrowErrorFunctions;     
} catch (e) {
  print('error:$e');
}
```

The app will not crash but I cannot catch the error in firebase, and I won't know there is an error, right?

What if I wanna don't crash, and at the same time I could catch the error with firebase, is it possible? And what is the correct usage?

Any help will be appreciate, thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reviewing the documentation on [reporting caught exceptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter#report-caught-exceptions), which is what you're trying to here.  It will look something like this:

```
try {
  final result = await someThrowErrorFunctions;     
} catch (e) {
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(e);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have saw this, I just wander is there a interceptor in which I can achieve this without writing `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(e);` in every catch block. And according the documentation, this recorded errors have a 8 times limit.

Comment: No, you have to add the code for each caught exception.